# Django: insert data into table which contains foregin key and many to many relation using serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-serializer

i have a table that contains many to many and foreign key relation

```
class TableRelation(models.Model):
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(table1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    table2 = models.ForeignKey(table2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    table3 = models.ManyToManyField(table3)
```

iam using mixins and generic view set for listing and updating. listing retrieve works fine . but when i update or create it shows
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `table1.serializers.TableRelationSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
so i have written a create methode in the serializer

```
class TableRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    table1 = Table1Serializer()
    table2 = Table2Serializer()
    table3 = Table3Serializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = TableRelation
        fields = ('id', 'table1', 'table2', 'table3',)
    def create(self, instance, validated_data):
        remove_table1 = validated_data.pop('table1',)
        remove_table2 = remove_table1.pop('table2')
        table_data = remove_table2.pop('table3')
        table1 = Table1.objects.create(**validated_data)
        table2 = Table2.objects.create(**validated_data)
        table3 = Table3.objects.create(**validated_data)
        TableRelation.objects.create(
            table1=table1, table2=table2, table3=table3, **table_data)
        return "fhfh"
```

then iam getting this error
TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'validated_data'
i have tried some other method then also iam getting this error
what is the proper way of creating an instance in many to many and foreign key columns containing tables?

Comment: Try removing instance form the create method and return {} instead of string

Comment: after removing the instance the error is gone .thanks. the way that i have written create method is write?. because unable to create that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks VJ Magar for your comment. that helped me to remove the create() missing error.
and i found how to insert data to table which contains foreign key and many to may relations using serializer

```
class TableRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    table1 = Table1Serializer(read_only=True)
    table1_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=table1.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    table2 = Table2Serializer(read_only=True)
    table2_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Table2.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    table3_type = Table3Serializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    table3_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Table3.objects.all(), write_only=True, many=True)
   def create(self, validated_data):
        data1 = validated_data.pop('table1_id')
        data2 = validated_data.pop('table2_id')
        data3 = validated_data.pop('table3_id')
        table_role = TableRelation.objects.create(
            table1_id=data1.id, table2_id=data2.id,  **validated_data)
        for table in data3:
            table_role.table3.add(table)
        return table_role
```